# Expand-Archive giving syntax error in PowerShell v5.1 (A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'DestinationPath') , Why?

Tags: powershell, shell, console, window, powershell-5.1

With an aim of a simple extraction of **.zip** file with minimum size (20MB) works perfectly fine in PowerShell **7.3.1** Version but not in **5.1**, Why?

**COMMAND:**

```
Expand-Archive -Path $Path\compressed.zip -DestinationPath $Path\Destination
```

**ERROR:**

> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name
> 'DestinationPath'

[image]

What's the silly mistake I did here, Or it won't work in PowerShell 5.1?

It should work as per the documentation given by Microsoft here [Expand Archive in PS 5.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-5.1#example-2-extract-the-contents-of-an-archive-in-the-current-folder)

[image]

Comment: That is very odd for sure. I dont see a problem with your code. Only thing I guess could be happening is if there is a custom function overriding the actual cmdlet. Try running the following: `Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Expand-Archive -Path $Path\compressed.zip -DestinationPath $Path\Destination`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding **@Santiago**'s comment as a Answer here as this is solved my mystery, So no one would miss it and save their time to resolve the issue.

I've added **Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive** to use it from the correct library.

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Expand-Archive -Path $Path\compressed.zip -DestinationPath $Path\Destination
```